# How to read 2 value once in for loop by Python?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

I have a class,com_and_url, containing 2 variable, com and url. Such as:

```
a = com_and_url(com, url)
```

And a file I want to read whose content is like this:

```
Google
www.google.com
yahoo
www.yahoo.com
facebook
www.facebook.com
```

So here is the psuedo code:

```
list_com_and_url = []

for com, url in f:
    list_com_and_url.append( com_and_url( com, url ) )
```

Can python do this? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
list_com_and_url = []
with open('my_file') as f:
    for line in f:
        name, url = line, next(f)
        list_com_and_url.append(zip(name, url))
```

Comment: @richmondwang It does work, but I don't find the use of `next(f)` inside the loop on `f` to be particularly readable.

Comment: @njzk2 next goes to next line and return the text. what you suggest?

Comment: @Hackaholic I have posted an answer. What I don't like with this, is that the loop itself is manipulated, and the contract of that for loop, which is basically "do this for each line in the file", is changed halfway through. (although I agree that the contract of the loop is more something like "read a line of the file, if the line exists, go in the loop", but since it is the generic for loop structure, it is the kind of things that can be easily overlooked.)

Comment: I like your way, which is really clear and readable. However, I don't know what is zip. Is it my class named 'com_and_url' or you rename my class to 'zip'?

Comment: @MarsLee zip is a basic python function

Comment: @MarsLee zip is a inbuilt function in python.

Comment: But I want to use name and url to create a class, Does 'zip' function work for me? Because I didn't find any code is used to create a class.
Besides, will your method make list out of range? because when for loop run to the last content, the next(f) will be out of range...

Comment: it will not go out of range, looping takes care of it.

Comment: Do you mean next function will protect your loop automatically?! Such an amazing function!

Comment: I know why it will not be out of range! Because the next function is counted in the for loop. So of course it will not out of range!

Comment: Can I know how to get zip(name, url) value?
    
    a = zip(name, url)
    a[0] a[1]

this doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

The shortest and (I find) clearest way is using slices:

```
lines = f.readlines()
for com, url in zip(lines[::2], lines[1::2]):
    # Do stuff
```

(nota: do not attempt this with files that don't fit in memory)

Comment: This is a precise way, and is optimized in term of runtime. But at memory use perspective it's a really expensive approach, specially when we are dealing with huge files.

Answer (score 0):

As an optimized way in term of memory (using iterators and refusing of loading whole of the lines in memory) you can use [`itertools.tee()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/itertools.html#itertools.tee) to create two independent iterator from your file object (which is an iterator) then use `itertools.islice()` to put the even lines in `f` and odd lines in `next_f` then use `zip()` function (in python 2 `itertools.izip()`) to create an iterator contain the pair columns.

```
from itertools import tee, islice

with open('my_file') as f:
     next_f, f = tee(f)
     next_f, f = islice(f, 0, None, 2), islice(next_f, 1, None, 2)
     list_com_and_url = [com_and_url( com, url ) for com, url in zip(f, next_f)]
```

Comment: why do you consume the first line?

Comment: Thank you for your answering! This is really a whole new method for me. I need a little time to digest it! Thank you :)

Comment: that does not do what the op wants. e.g., for an input of `[1,2,3,4]`, the output is expected to be `[[1,2], [3,4]]`, this returns `[[1,2], [2,3], [3,4]]`

Answer (score 0):

You can just read two lines at a time

```
with open('file.txt') as f:
    lines = f.read().splitlines()
    com_and_url = (lines[i:i+2] for i in range(0, len(lines), 2))
```

This returns a generator, so to output to a list

```
print(list(com_and_url))
```

outputs

```
[['Google', 'www.google.com'],
 ['yahoo', 'www.yahoo.com'],
 ['facebook', 'www.facebook.com']]
```